# How to remove duplicate values inside array in a document in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

This is the sample sample json, inside text array I have duplicate values like "SEQUENCE": 1 is repeated, I want only one record to exist, can some suggest how to remove the duplicate record. I have 100 documents like this.

Please suggest me a single query which i can use to do this.

```
"description": {
      "content": [],
      "details": [
        {
          "CONTENT_TYPE_ID": 0,
          "DESCRIPTION_NAME": "Bullets",
          "DESCRIPTION_TYPE_ID": 2,
          "TAB_SEQ": 0,
          "TEXT": [
            {
              "SEQUENCE": 1,
              "DESCRIPTION": "Double sided print, allows complete application on one sheet"
            },
            {
              "SEQUENCE": 1,
              "DESCRIPTION": "Double sided print, allows complete application on one sheet"
            },
            {
              "SEQUENCE": 1,
              "DESCRIPTION": "Double sided print, allows complete application on one sheet"
            },
            {
              "SEQUENCE": 2,
              "DESCRIPTION": "8-1/2\" x 11\""
            },
            {
              "SEQUENCE": 2,
              "DESCRIPTION": "8-1/2\" x 11\""
            },
            {
              "SEQUENCE": 2,
              "DESCRIPTION": "8-1/2\" x 11\""
            },
            {
              "SEQUENCE": 3,
              "DESCRIPTION": "One-part"
            },
            {
              "SEQUENCE": 3,
              "DESCRIPTION": "One-part"
            },
            {
              "SEQUENCE": 3,
              "DESCRIPTION": "One-part"
            },
            {
              "SEQUENCE": 4,
              "DESCRIPTION": "3-hole punched"
            },
            {
              "SEQUENCE": 4,
              "DESCRIPTION": "3-hole punched"
            },
            {
              "SEQUENCE": 4,
              "DESCRIPTION": "3-hole punched"
            },
            {
              "SEQUENCE": 5,
              "DESCRIPTION": "50 forms per pack, 2 packs included"
            },
            {
              "SEQUENCE": 5,
              "DESCRIPTION": "50 forms per pack, 2 packs included"
            },
            {
              "SEQUENCE": 5,
              "DESCRIPTION": "50 forms per pack, 2 packs included"
            },
            {
              "SEQUENCE": 6,
              "DESCRIPTION": "Employment and other laws change periodically.  Check the laws in your jurisdiction to see if this form is acceptable."
            },
            {
              "SEQUENCE": 6,
              "DESCRIPTION": "Employment and other laws change periodically.  Check the laws in your jurisdiction to see if this form is acceptable."
            },
            {
              "SEQUENCE": 6,
              "DESCRIPTION": "Employment and other laws change periodically.  Check the laws in your jurisdiction to see if this form is acceptable."
            }
          ]
        }]
    }
```

Comment: You could try to [remove duplicates with an unique index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-creation/#index-creation-duplicate-dropping), but I am not sure if it would drop only the array entries and not the whole document where the uniqueness-violation occurs.

Comment: @Philipp: thank you for the suggestion. the data has already been inserted to mongodb, and i have too many columns with duplicate entries like this. please suggest any ideas to query and remove this kind of data.

Comment: an unique index can be created with the `dropDupes:true` option to automatically remove any existing data which violates it. Otherwise you won't be able to solve this problem with a single query. You could just use aggregation to get the data with removed duplicates, drop the collection and recreate it with the data you got.

Comment: If you really only have 100 documents, just write a simple one time function to do the logic. There's not a simple one use command to do this logic.

Comment: @Philip: indexing works on a *document* level, so `dropDups` will drop  subsequent documents that would not match the unique constraint. As WiredPrairie suggests there is no server-side command to this, so the best approach is to fix with some application logic that iterates and fixes up the 100 or so documents.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can build up a new collection with the aggregation pipeline, my approach:

1. $unwind TEXT
2. $group to eliminate duplicates
3. $group again to reconstruct the document
4. $project to finish the reconstruction
5. $out in another collection

   db.description.aggregate([
    {$unwind : "$details.TEXT"},
    {$gruop : {"_id" : {"key" : "$_id", "TEXT" : "$details.TEXT"}}},
    {$gruop : {"_id" : "$_id.key", "details.TEXT" : {$push : "$_id.TEXT"}}}
   ]);

I didn't test it and you will have to work the details but i think this will do the job!